# The records in certain fields in my database grid show up as (WIDEMEMO)

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm currently working with a dbGrid in delphi that is supposed to display the fields EmailAddress, DonatorCell and DonatorName. The records in the Email and DonatorCell fields all show (WIDEMEMO) even though there are actual valid records there. I've tried increasing the sizes of these fields but nothing. How do can I fix this?

Comment: What is the database you use and which Delphi component, what is the the SQL definition for your fields, if not WideMemo, what do you expect? Please show the code you are using (A simplified version of the code, but working code) as a [minimal, complete, verifiable and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
 With such example, we will be able to reproduce your problem, understand it and try to solve it.

Comment: 1) Which database (Access, Sql Server. MySql, etc) and 2) which Delphi db-access components (ADO, DBX, etc) are you using?  3) If you right-click on the dataset which feeds the DBGrid, select 'Fields editor' and select 'Add all fields', what field type does it create for the 3 fields you mention?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why dbGrid is now showing contents of the mentioned fields is that in your database they are declared as memo fields (such fields can contain text of arbitrary length which could also contain special characters like new line separator) which makes displaying of contents of such fields in a single cell not trivial therefore by default it isn't done automatically.

You could do this by using OnGetText event for these particular cells in order to extract the text contents from such fields but you may lose some of its fomratting and as such it may not necessarily be shown in a same ways as it would be in TMemoField component instead.

You can read more about this and how to handle such scenarios in an article [Displaying and Editing MEMO Fields in Delphi's TDBGrid](https://www.thoughtco.com/displaying-and-editing-memo-fields-in-delphis-tdbgrid-4092538) written by Žarko Gajič

Comment: The problem the OP describes can arise when a Delphi project using Access is migrated from a pre-Unicode version of Delphi to a post-Unicode one, even when the Access column is not a memo type.